# Looking for help understanding simple Prolog code

Tags: prolog

I have this basic code.

```
list_length([], 0).
list_length([_|Tail], L) :-
    L #= L0+1,
    L #> 0,
    list_length(Tail,L0).
```

I cannot figure out where L0 comes from. How could we ever deduce what L equals? In order to know what L equals we must know the value of L0. Is this because we are reasoning inductively instead of deductively?

I feel like once I understand this code I will begin to understand Prolog as a whole much better.

Comment: `#=` is from the `clfd` package. It basically is a constraint that "fires" when one of the variables gets grounded. So if `L0` eventually gets grounded (due to recursion), `L` will take the value `L0 + 1`. `L0` is just a variable like every identifier that starts with an uppercase in Prolog.

Comment: You would be astonished by the complexity hidden in this 'simple' code. Indeed, it's not ever Prolog code, rather a special DSL ([Domain Specific Language](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)) for integer constraints solving. So, understanding this code is **orthogonal** to understanding Prolog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could we could ever deduce what `L` equals? In order to know what `L` equals we must know the value of `L0`.

The [**`#=/2`** predicate [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%23%3D%20/%202) comes from the [**`clpfd`** library [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd). This is a constraint logic programming library. It offers a set of constraints. These constraints are not just aliasses for `is/2` or `=:=/2`, but work often in both directions, and furthermore also allows to enforce the constraints when the variables are grounded. It thus can postpone evaluation.

In this specific case it thus means that if `L0` takes a value, `L` will take the value `L0+1`. If `L` has a value, for example because you made a query `length([1,4,2,5], 5)`. It will also check the constraint and thus fail if `5 #= 3+1` is evaluated.